# Counting words and delete strings from a text file in unix

Tags: file, shell, unix, string

I have a question for you: I have a big log file and I want to clean it. I'm interested only in strings which contain determinate word and I want to delete the other strings. i.e.:

```
access ok from place1
access ko from place1
access ok from place2
access ko from place2
access ok from place3
access ko from place3
......
```

And I want to obtain only the 'place2' entry:

```
access ok from place2
access ko from place2
```

How can I do it?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

grep "place2" /path/to/log/file > cleanedFile.txt

I wrote a [blog post about combining find/sed/grep](http://developmentality.wordpress.com/2010/09/07/unix-tip-3-introduction-to-find-grep-sed/) - you might be interested.

Answer (score 2):

Try this grep command:

```
grep "\<place2\>" log-file > out-file
```

`\<` and `\>` will make sure to match full word thus inplace2 will NOT be matched.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep "\<place2\>" file.log > file.out
wc file.out
```

wc (word count) for counting the words. But for 2 questions, you should normally open two questions. :)

Answer (score 0):

Another take, select lines where the 4th column equals "place2"

```
awk '$4 == "place2"' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike most other answers, this modifies the file in-place and does not need further renaming.

```
sed -i -n '/place2/p' /var/log/file
```

This assumes GNU sed. If you don't have GNU sed but have perl:

```
perl -i -ne '/place2/ && print' /var/log/file
```

Answer (score 0):

These 2 examples does in-place editing as well.

```
$ awk '$NF=="place2"{print $0>FILENAME}' file

$ ruby -i.bak -ane 'print if $F[-1]=="place2"' file
```

There are other ways to files these lines

```
sed -i.bak -n '/place2$/p' file

grep 'place2$' file > temp && mv temp file
```

Purely using the shell

```
while read -r line; do case $line in  *place2) echo "$line";; esac; done < file > temp && mv temp file
```